# Shower curb: Fill in holes in cement blocks before tiling?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, cement

I am putting a curb in my shower using small cinder blocks. Do I need to fill the holes with cement before tiling?

Comment: are the openings in the blocks on top or on side?

Comment: Are you covering the holes in the block with anything (e.g. cement board)? You need support under the tiles...

Comment: A photo may be helpful here or the dimensions I can’t think of any small cinder blocks off the top of my head. Structural brick with the holes would not need filling but cynder blocks normally would.